# Acceleration mechanism

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, particle-accelerators

Ionized gas, if compressed (by magnetic field) to a mm cylinder, collapses rapidly and accelerates the e/ions to MeV.
What could be the possible acceleration mechanism?
The question is how a magnetic field, while compresses the ions, cause acceleration? How the related equation could be written for such condition?

Comment: Do you have a link of the experiment?

Comment: Not really. This is an ionized gas compressed by surrounding magnetic. This produces and electric field that accelerates the enclosed ions but I don’t know how could be the mechanism. How the equation is written?

(magnetic field) is proportional to (electric field)

Comment: is this an imaginary situation? is it like tis https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsjWGz3YE5o ?

Comment: It's more like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRc7u8XN1fg                                      What I want to know: isn’t it possible that time varying magnetic field surrounding ions, produces an electric field that accelerates the enclosed ions? And write down the related equations!

Comment: as this shows, https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.873869 it needs a complicated calculation to understand it mathematically,

Comment: This is far beyond my understanding. As a BSc student I just want to see how the condition I mentioned above could be formulated simply?

Comment: No, it cannot because it is a system with many parameters, it is not just the circles that a charged particle makes in  magnetic field  with Bqv=mv^2/r, the higher the B the smaller the r, which explains the video I linked to.

Comment: Then, any reference with simpler description please? The one in the last link looks different from what I asked though complicated!

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html#c3   http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/movchg.html

Comment: I found the explanation in the following article that probably describe what I am looking for but ask to help me to understand it: Physics of Fluids 13, 2858 (1970)
There are a few points here:
It's a ring type current, I(r).
Current density variation means that the current at each r has a different value.
If these two are correct then what does it mean that 1. the current variation toward axis results in a magnetic field 2. variation in r direction yields azimuthal magnetic field (theta) and axial electric field (z).

Comment: sorry, I cannot help, except to remind that changing magnetic fields create electric fields and changing electric fields create magnetic fields. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magloo.html